# Do Frodo and Legolas have any discussion in the entire Lord of the Rings?

Tags: the-lord-of-the-rings, tolkiens-legendarium

Did Frodo and Legolas have any discussion in the entire Lord of the Rings? From what I remember (from the movies), Legolas said to him in Rivendell "And my bow!" and then they never talked again.

**Do they have any discussions on the books or the movies?**

I remember that he talked with the other members of the Fellowship, but I cannot recall any discussions with Legolas.

Comment: Would *you* want to talk to Frodo?

Comment: To clarify, are you asking solely about the books? Or are you also asking if there are any additional examples in the movies?

Comment: Interestingly Legolas isn't the only character (in the movies) with this quirk. The film commentaries pick up on the fact that one of the other hobbits (M or P) only get one line to Frodo [which he doesn't even reply to] in the entire trilogy as well.

Comment: Well if we're counting something as simple as "And my bow!", I'm pretty sure Frodo yells "Legolas!" or something when he comes into his bedroom in Return of the King and the hobbits are playing in his bed and... well, it's a lot less weird than I made it sound.

Comment: I'd like to point out that at the very end of the movie, When Frodo is lying in bed and everyone comes in to see him Sam, Mary, pippin etc, although there is no actual sound, you can see Frodo say the names of all of them, apart from Legolas. Like what is that about? It looks like he's forgotten his name. I always find it so funny.

Answer (score 55, accepted):

Yes.

On the Great River, after the first ambush by Orcs (which doesn't appear in the movie) and after Legolas shoots down the Nazgul's Fell Beast (likewise), we have the following exchange (the conversation opens with Sam):

> 'Well, I can remember three nights there for certain, and I seem to remember several more, but I would take my oath it was never a whole month. Anyone would think that time did not count in there!'
>
> 'And perhaps that was the way of it,' said Frodo. 'In that land, maybe, we were in a time that has elsewhere long gone by. It was not, I think, until Silverlode bore us back to Anduin that we returned to the time that flows through mortal lands to the Great Sea. And I don't remember any moon, either new or old, in Caras Galadhon: only stars by night and sun by day.'
>
> Legolas stirred in his boat. 'Nay, time does not tarry ever,' he said; 'but change and growth is not in all things and places alike. For the Elves the world moves, and it moves both very swift and very slow. Swift, because they themselves change little, and all else fleets by: it is a grief to them. Slow, because they do not count the running years, not for themselves. The passing seasons are but ripples ever repeated in the long long stream. Yet beneath the Sun all things must wear to an end at last.'
>
> 'But the wearing is slow in Lórien,' said Frodo. `The power of the Lady is on it. Rich are the hours, though short they seem, in Caras Galadhon, where Galadriel wields the Elven-ring.'

Aside from that, there are plenty of other occasions where Frodo and Legolas were together and clearly had opportunity for conversation, but what they may or may not have said is unrecorded; here I give just two as examples:

- During Frodo's watch in Moria he first sees Gollum (or at least what can be deduced to be his eyes); Legolas takes the next watch.
- On entering Lorien and after being waylaid by the Elves, Frodo and Legolas are the first two to climb up a *flet*, and they climb up together.

Despite the fact that any conversation is unrecorded, that doesn't mean that it didn't happen (absence of evidence is not evidence of absence) and it would be very odd indeed if they didn't talk at least for the first of these examples.

Comment: Re: "absence of evidence is not evidence of absence," let's also keep in mind that they were living and traveling with each other for months, including two months of doing very little in Rivendell. Even if there were zero conversations recorded in the books, I think it'd be fair to assume they still happened fairly often.

Comment: "Legolas! Have you seen Merry's pack?";"No, I don't think you'll hit that tree over *there*";"You almost hit Gimli there"

Answer (score 11):

Well (in the books) there's also the time in Lothlórien after they cross the river of Nimrodel.

> Almost Frodo fancied that he could hear a voice singing, mingled with the sound of the water.
>
> 'Do you head the voice of Nimrodel?' asked Legolas. 'I will sing you a song of the Maiden Nimrodel, who bore the same name as the stream beside which she lived long ago. It is a fair song in our woodland tongue; but this is how it runs in the Westron Speech, as some in Rivendell now sing it.' In a voice hardly to be heard amid the rustle of the leaves above them he began: [*song is sang*]
>
> The voice of Legolas faltered, and the song ceased. 'I cannot sing any more,' he said. 'That is but a part, for I have forgotten much. It is a long and sad, for it tells how sorrow came upon Lothlórien, Lórien of the Blossom, when the Dwarves awakened evil in the mountains.'

Answer (score -3):

I totally see where you are coming from.Yet, I doubt you've read the book,for in the book Legolas and Frodo have quite a few conversations. In the movies, Legolas isn't exactly a main or principle role.The only conversations Elijah Wood ( Frodo) made were with GOLLUM while going to Mount Doom,Sam throughout the movie,Gandalf at some parts,and Aragorn and other various characters.

So,in the movie,you are correct. The only sentence Legolas directly says to Frodo is 'And my bow,'.

Comment: While correct, this doesn't really add anything to the existing answers.

Comment: Well,Richard,I was only using a bit of knowledge from my brain!Hahaha!